# How to tag a page in facebook while posting an image on facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

09-05 13:14:42.500: E/response=0(7474): ==={"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}

final String inputParm = post_id + "/tags?to=" + "pageId"  ;

```
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, faceboo.getAccessToken());   
                        Log.e("params TOKEN",""+faceboo.getAccessToken());
                        mAsyncRunner.request(inputParm, params, "POST", new RequestListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e("response=0","==="+response);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e("onIOException","==="+e);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFileNotFoundException(
                                    FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e("FileNotFoundException","==="+e);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onMalformedURLException(
                                    MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e("MalformedURLException","==="+e);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e("FacebookError","==="+e);
                            }
                        }, null);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You dont even explain anything. You are not showing interest. You didnt read how to ask a question. You dont insert the code into code tags and that piece you did has a unnecessary nesting which makes it not to fit

Comment: And you didnt tag which language is that code in

Comment: Do you think we can help you with the info you provide

Comment: i am coding in java (android) and trying to implement tagging functionality of facebook where i want to tag a page of facebook and share it on my wall.

Comment: As i have mentioned above i want to tag a page in facebook while posting an image on facebook in android